# How do I disable the command 'stop' from doing anything?

Tags: command-line, upstart

When I'm working on a Minecraft server I type 'stop' to stop the server, and sometimes I don't pay enough attention to gnome terminal and I type 'stop' when the server is already stopped, instead I get

```
unity-settings-daemon stop/killed, process 1998
```

unsurprisingly some settings seem to stop working, Firefox shuts down and it's just generally annoying that this command is so easy for me to mis-run. Is there any way I can disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not "disable", but "mask".

Note that `stop` is `/sbin/stop`. Look at your `$PATH` (`echo $PATH | tr ":" "\n"`). Anything named `stop` in a directory in your `PATH` that is *earlier* will be executed instead. If `~/bin` is earlier, you could create `~/bin/stop` containing:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "To really run 'stop', type '/sbin/stop`"
exit 0
```

or

Define an alias in your `~/.bashrc`:

```
alias stop="echo \"To really run 'stop', type '/sbin/stop`\""
```